# Deck the halls with bubble wrap?

Tags: walls, insulation, materials, winter, rental

In order to insulate a room, would it make sense to apply a layer of bubble wrap to my walls/ceiling? What about some other material like mylar or foylon? What major factors would affect the answer to this question? In particular, would the amount of sunlight coming into the room have a significant effect?

If yes, how much benefit would I get from <100% coverage, e.g. from missing some uneven spots on the wall or missing the ceiling?

(Context: I am already taking a number of steps to insulate my windows. I am also a renter of a second floor unit with somewhat irregular construction, which I take to mean that it is a hassle for me to modify the exterior or the inside of the wall and I cannot assume that "best practices" were followed in the construction process.)

Comment: You keep heading down the road to "died in a fire" - perhaps you should move to a better-insulated apartment rather than killing yourself with flammable/toxic-smoke wall firebait.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for the warning; I hope you know that I do appreciate your advice and have been rejecting plans that people tell me are unsafe. That's a big part of why I am asking these questions. I don't mean to come off as disrespectful or dismissive just because I keep asking questions in search of unusual solutions that might work for me. Let me know if there is anything I can do to be more respectful.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Does your warning apply to the full range of materials in my question (bubble wrap, mylar/foylon, anything else that occurs to you to prevent heat loss)?

Comment: Virtually all plastic (foam or sheet) or non-treated fabric is a major fire hazard. Most fire hazards kill you by toxic smoke. Normal wall construction puts insulating materials behind a barrier (such as sheetrock) that prevents them from being directly exposed to flame. Dorm room "mock fires" seem to be the best / most common videos showing what happens on the internet, though there may be others.

Comment: What about foylon? Looks like it is partially plastic.

Comment: @Ecnerwal While we are on the subject, how flammable is fiberglass and how toxic if melted/ignited?

Comment: Foylon, specifically, appears to be a fibrglass/aluminum product with good fire performance as reported by the manufacturer. Fiberglass (itself) is not flammable. It has mechanical hazards if left eposed, since breathing in or having your skin penetrated by tiny glass bits is not a good thing.

Comment: Haha, sounds like that uncle might have saved me from an early toxic fumes death :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would select non-flammable insulating materials such as rock-wool, or fiberglass (fully puffed up; mashing it *badly hurts* its performance).  To use these, you will need some sort of framing to hold it up.  It can't just be taped to a wall.

It's not out of the question to frame a room *inside* a rental house; I've seen it done. However this is the wrong year to be buying lumber and building supplies: COVID shut down the logging and milling earlier this year, meanwhile everyone stuck at home has gone on a remodeling binge, meanwhile new-home construction remains a very strong market.

However, you *really need* to work the normal insulation priority list: sealing of doors and windows first, window treatments second, then walls pretty much last.

Comment: Thanks! Your last sentence describes my plan; I may not even get to the walls this year. Do you have any thoughts on reflective materials?

Comment: @capet Yeah, ask the manufacturer about their albedo. If they don't beat 91%, stick with white paint.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, albedo is about the full spectrum. Would it be reasonable to also focus on the infrared part of the spectrum specifically?

Comment: Sure if you prefer heat from other parts of the spectrum.  Say are you trying to keep out cold, or heat?

Comment: I'm trying to keep out cold. So it sounds like you're saying 1. yes, albedo is the full spectrum  2. no, there is no point in looking at just infrared. Right?

Comment: Well I wouldn't bother with reflectors then.  Infrared radiation will stop at the first non-transparent surface, and that'll be inside your insulation envelope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113387/discussion-between-capet-and-harper-reinstate-monica). Obviously I don't have to tell you this, but no pressure. You've been super-generous already, here and other places.

Answer (score 2):

As an active landlord, we know that there are places that will insulate the insides of the walls for you without ripping the drywall off (assuming there is a cavity in the wall to insulate). The contractor drills a large enough hole at the top of the wall between the studs and blows in insulation (called “drill and blow”). Get an estimate on this and send it to your landlord and ask to split the costs. This get you better insulated at half the price. The landlord is happy as their rental unit is now more desirable in the long run. Do the same on a window quote. Take action and get a quote to send to them for consideration. If you’re giving the landlord a 50% discount by splitting the costs it’s a win for them as they keep 100% of the improvements as you move out. You on the other hand get exactly what you want and don’t have to have the hassle of moving again. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Styrofoam sheets are a common insulator.  You can use it directly against concrete and other surfaces where moisture intrusion is likely.  It's very common on garage doors and in basements.

If you really want to know about bubble wrap as an insulator, you can check for the R-value of **foil-faced bubble wrap** insulating products.  I don't think it's very good compared to other types of available thermal insulation; probably why it's not common.

Comment: Thanks! I will mark this as the answer tomorrow. Do you have any thoughts about the reflective materials?

Comment: Before going this route I would read @ecnerwal comment, styrofoam insulation usually requires a non flammable covering like Sheetrock. When styrofoam burns and it will burn really well it puts off toxic gas, so not only is it flammable it can create a toxic gas cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Beal. Do you think that foil facing or some other "easy covering" could be used to mitigate this risk?

Comment: Yeah except Styrofoam is basically made of gasoline.  In fact if you dissolve it into gasoline, you get napalm.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica So "yes but not enough for a reasonable person"?

Comment: @capet, no, an 'easy covering' won't do it, since if you let the heat of the fire get to it, it'll just melt into a liquid and run into the fire that way.  You really need something like drywall over it, which will protect it from the heat of the fire as well as covering it.  Drywall itself won't even prevent that forever, but it's designed to last long enough to make sure everyone has time to get out of the house before letting the fire burn through it.

Comment: Thanks @Nate S. What about polyiso?

Comment: @capet There's basically no solution for you as a renter to put up some sort of temporary, fire-safe insulation.  Maybe you could put wool blankets on the wall, but even that isn't going to do much since it won't seal well.

Comment: Not sure -- I don't know the fire performance characteristics of every type of insulation off the top of my head, but the manufacturers of said insulation absolutely do, and they'll put it in their product literature, so very likely you can look it up.  If they say you must put drywall over it, that's because they tried setting it on fire without and bad things happened, so follow their instructions.

Comment: @Steve Sether Is there a way to make it seal well? I know I need to avoid compressing most insulating materials. Other than installing framing around the window, could I use some kind of straps or tracks?

Comment: @Nate S. You could have fooled me, you seem super-knowledgeable! If I want to be more conservative than the instruction given by the manufacturer, are there standard metrics that I can also partially rely on? One thing I often see is that a product is designated "class bla fire retardant." Is that a reasonable guide to overall fire safety when used as directed?

Comment: @capet, yes, that's exactly how I'd go about it -- look up those fire rating classes and what they mean, and then buy a product with a rating that you're comfortable with.  And your last point is critical -- those ratings assume you're using them as directed, and if you don't, they're meaningless.  A product that says it's very fire safe but must have drywall over it may well be very flammable without the required drywall.

Comment: @Nate S Cool, thanks! For products with a ton of uses, how come I have not seem them with a bunch of different fire ratings? Maybe I haven't looked hard enough. And then I guess my other question is more vague: For a given use, fire safety seems like a multi-dimensional thing. Like I would prefer for my material not to ignite, but then maybe it could also melt, smoke, deform, release toxic gases, conduct heat into another dangerous material, etc. Do you have any layperson's description of what fire retardant classes are supposed to be telling me (and maybe what other metrics I should look at)?

Comment: As for styrofoam and napalm yup, a liquid candle spilled on Styrofoam turned a basement into a heck of a mess. after the cleanup and structural repair I re-wired the building 3 dwelling units very expensive. There are foam board types of insulation I have only used a few times but I think they are flammable (foil faced) because we had to fire stop at the top of the wall and at the first floor, floor. Balloon built structure. And the walls were sheet rocked. I have also used to insulate duct work on request, Owens Corning made some but again it was outside the duct I prefer fiberglass bats.

Comment: @Steve Sether Thanks! I don't think my landlord will mind some amount of damage, at least to the paint and drywall.

Comment: @Steve Sether Cool, thanks! This might sound like a joke, but it's not: Is there some kind of paint meant to maximize static cling?